# react how to change an input css without doing anything on the input

Tags: css, reactjs, input

I've fetched anwsers from a survey I made and i want to display the result.
It is a notation (1 to 5) and I want to show the result like the screeshot. 
The numbers are in a square and the number who's the answer is in an other color.
But I"m stuck.
How do I compare the note I fetched with the value on my input ?
I"m not doing an onChange so I can't use event.target.value.

I'd like to something like :

```
className={`square ${element.answer===value && "red"}`}
```

my code :

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./index.css";
import axios from "axios";

/* import icons */
import FileWhite from "../../assets/img/file-text-white.svg";
import StarWhite from "../../assets/img/star-white.svg";
import Minus from "../../assets/img/minus.svg";

const Responses = ({ id }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (id) {
      const fetchData = async () => {
        try {
          const response = await axios.get(
            `http://localhost:3001/responses/${id}`
          );
          console.log(response.data);
          setData(response.data);
          setIsLoading(false);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error.message);
        }
      };
      fetchData();
    }
  }, [id]);

  return isLoading ? (
    <div>Chargement en cours...</div>
  ) : (
    <div id="responses">
      {data.map((responses) => {
        return responses.answers.map((element) => {
          return (
            <article>
              <div className="question">
                <div
                  className={`type ${
                    element.type === "texte" ? "orange" : "red"
                  }`}
                >
                  <span>{element.type === "texte" ? "1" : "2"}</span>
                  <img src={Minus} alt="" />
                  <img
                    src={element.type === "texte" ? FileWhite : StarWhite}
                    alt=""
                  />
                </div>
                <div>{element.question}</div>
              </div>
              {element.type === "texte" ? (
                <div className="answerText">{element.answer}</div>
              ) : (
                <div className="answerNote">
                  <div className="square">
                    <input type="radio" id="note1" name="note" value="1" />
                    <label htmlFor="note1">1</label>
                  </div>

                  <div className="square">
                    <input type="radio" id="note2" name="note" value="2" />
                    <label htmlFor="note2">2</label>
                  </div>

                  <div className="square">
                    <input type="radio" id="note3" name="note" value="3" />
                    <label htmlFor="note3">3</label>
                  </div>

                  <div className="square">
                    <input type="radio" id="note4" name="note" value="4" />
                    <label htmlFor="note4">4</label>
                  </div>

                  <div className="square">
                    <input type="radio" id="note5" name="note" value="5" />
                    <label htmlFor="note5">5</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              )}
            </article>
          );
        });
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Responses;
```

How do I get the value of the input to get this result ? (see screenshot)
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

it should be like this

```
className={`square ${element.answer===value ? "red" : "" }`}
```

Comment: I tried it but I've got an error "value is not defined"...
The className is not in the input but in the div above which contains the input.
I tried in input, same error.

Comment: please check if you getting data to `element.answer` or `value`

Comment: I've got a data for element.answer but like I said, I use the input to display the result from element.answer so I dont do anything on the input. That's why I can't figure out how to change the css.
I only have value=1, value=2 and so on, on the different inputs.
I'll edit and post my code.

Comment: so this is what you want for item 4? ` <div className="square red">`

Comment: you can avoid duplicate `<div className="square">
                    <input type="radio" id="note1" name="note" value="1" />
                    <label htmlFor="note1">1</label>
                  </div>`  just use map over array..

Comment: element.answer has a number between 1 and 5 (not always the same number).
I have 5 squares (radio buttons) and I want the one with the same number as element.answer to have a red background color.

Comment: can you share sample data for `answers` object?

Comment: i tried but I don't know how to format it here so it looks lisible...

Comment: please check this https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-kare-ypn2b?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I finally did get to the result I wanted.
I drop the inputs ans put div instead.

Comment: awesome..was wondering why you have input as you not going to edit data..its readonly.